# Get old package version that is no longer listed in PyPI history

Tags: python, tensorflow, pypi

Is there a way to get old package versions that are no longer listed in the PyPI history?

I am trying to get my hands on an older version of tf-nightly (< 2.4.0.dev20200819, ideally 2.4.0.dev20200817), but it is no longer listed in PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/#history

Comment: What CPython version do you need: `cp35`, `cp36`, `cp37`, or `cp38`? What platform: `macos`, `windows` or `manylinux`?

Comment: I'm running Python 3.6.9 on ubuntu 18.04, so I suppose that'd be `cp36` on `manylinux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: no, there isn't a way for a regular user to get a deleted distribution.

However, PyPI keeps all distributions around indefinitely, so the original download URLs will continue to work if you have them.

The distribution in question is here: http://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/41/5a365a293965a01f9200afcc8988a020a6fefcf3a4bf248158c91f280dff/tf_nightly-2.4.0.dev20200817-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl